# Passing partial array to a function

Tags: arrays, vb.net, function, copy, partial

This is really a question about efficiency I guess...

I have a device that gives me (image) data in an array that I then pass to a third party library as follows:

```
Private Sub NewData(TheData() as ushort)

    LibraryFunction(TheData)

End Sub
```

This works just fine, EXCEPT that for the device to run efficiently it uses a ring buffer, for which it requires that the image data array is 'n' times the length of the image data, where 'n' is the depth of the ring buffer.  This is fine as when I receive data from the device I also receive the index of the image frame.

What I want to write then is:

```
Private Const ImageDataLength = somenumber
Private Sub NewData(TheData() as ushort, bufferIndex as long)

    LibraryFunction(TheData(bufferIndex * ImageDataLength))

End Sub
```

BUT the LibraryFunction will only accept an array (of ushort), so to make this work I have had to do the following:

```
Private Const ImageDataLength = somenumber
Private Sub NewData(TheData() as ushort, bufferIndex as long)

    Dim tmp(ImageDataLength) As ushort
    Array.Copy(TheData, (bufferIndex * ImageDataLength, tmp, 0, ImageDataLength)
    LibraryFunction(tmp)

End Sub
```

Again, works OK BUT there is the obvious extra data copy going on.  Given that each chunk of image data is actually 15MB and I'm trying to keep frame rates up, I'd love to lose the `array.copy`

Any ideas on how to make this as efficient as possible?

Thanks

Comment: When you pass an array to a function, only the reference of that array is passed. So if the `LibraryFunction` is under your control, you should optimize it to work with the passed in array. Most possibly an overload accepting the `bufferIndex` should do.

Comment: Are you pushing these chunks through a wire or wireless connection or this is all in-process?

Comment: Hi.  It's in-process at this point in code.  "LibraryFunction" is part of a third-party system, so I only have the function as exposed by the library to work with - hence posing the question here!   (old version used to take a pointer the data, but new .Net version seems to just accept an array as a parameter)